# Is history.state always the same as popstate event.state?

Tags: javascript, html5-history

Is `history.state` always the same as popstate `event.state` ?

```
window.addEventListener("popstate", function (event){
    console.log(history.state === event.state); // ALWAYS TRUE
    // IT SEEMS
}, false);
```

If yes, what purposes to have the same thing twice.

Comment: If I read https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#history-traversal:dom-history-state correctly, then yes, `PopStateEvent.state` should always be the same as `history.state` since in the procedure, `history.state` should be updated to this `state`. As to the *purposes* of having this twice... hard to tell for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes they should always represent the same state.

According to [the specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#history-traversal:dom-history-state) when a browser is requested to perform an History traversal,

> 13. Set `history.state` to *state*.

Where *state* is the same as in *16.1*

> 1. If *state changed* is true, then fire an event named `popstate` at the `Document` object's `Window` object, using `PopStateEvent`, with the bubbles attribute initialized to true and the `state` attribute initialized ***state***.

<sup>emphasis mine</sup>

What the other answer's code proves is that Google Chrome doesn't return the same object, but a copy.
Nevertheless, both states are the same, and UAs don't seem to have to respect the *[SameObject]* policy on this state object anyway.

So in order to check equality, one should check the content of the state object, and not use direct equality check.

```js
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
  console.log('same state',
    JSON.stringify(event.state) === JSON.stringify(history.state) // always true
  );
};

const obj1 = {page: 1};
history.pushState(obj1, "title 1", "?page=1");

console.log('[SameObject]', history.state === obj1); // false
console.log(history.state); // {page: 1}

history.pushState({page: 2}, "title 2", "?page=2");
history.replaceState({page: 3}, "title 3", "?page=3");
history.back();
history.back(); 
history.go(2);
```

As to why set it in two different places, I have to admit I don't have a solid answer...

Comment: which one should be used in the event handler ?

Comment: @WalleCyril that won't do any difference, none of these would be strictly equal to the original object you passed, but both would be copy of the same object, so really, it doesn't matter.